# Change main branch in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I messed up and pushed a branch to bitbucket that wasn't meant to be main branch.

[image]

I can't make a new repository and I have limited access to this one. I tried renaming it. I ended up deleting .git folder, now I can't push to that branch or pull it. When I try to pull it says:

```
(files)...
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I want to have branch named main (as the main branch) and then cms-fe that branches out from it.

Can someone help me get out from this mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to have branch named main (as the main branch) and then cms-fe that branches out from it.

Since you dont have admin rights we will have to rename your branch and than push it with the new name:

```
# rename the local branch
git branch -m cms-fe main
```

Now that the branch has a new name we will push the new name to the remote

```
git push origin main
```

Now we will delete the old branch that you pushed with the old name

```
git push origin :cms-fe
```

Branch out from the main branch

```
git checkout main
git checkout -b cms-fe

# upload the branch to the remote server
git push origin cms-fe
```

Comment: When I do `git push origin :cms-fe`, I get `![remote rejected] cms-fe (deletion of the current branch prohibited)`. Seems like I don't have the permission to delete it.